# How to return value from a css transform in js?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to return a value from a css transform matrix in js.

The element is a div with the following css:

```
transform: translateY(-560px)
```

In my JS I'm currently getting the matrix by doing this:

```
  const el = document.querySelector('[data-holder]')
  return getComputedStyle(el).transform
```

Above code gives me:

```
matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -560)
```

How can i extract that last value from the matrix?

Comment: What have you tried? The first thing that comes to mind is a regex delineating the `matrix()` arguments as capture groups

Comment: @Phil What you see in the post is current progress. Regex i can't write myself, bu please provide me with one if you're able to!

Comment: Parsing computed CSS seems brittle. You might get different values from different browsers. Can you not infer the value given the styles are known? Ie, if all `[data-holder]` elements have `translateY(-560px)`, isn't the value always going to be `-560`?

Comment: @Phil No, its set in a js function, and need to stay as is for multiple reasons.

Comment: Use the ```getComputedStyle``` function to get the matrix as a string, and then use *regex*(match) to extract the value.

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation Sure! Do you mind writing it for me?

Comment: If it's set in a JS function, can you not also record the value somewhere better than CSS? For example, in another data attribute... `el.dataset.transformTranslateY = '-560'`

Comment: @Phil Ah yes, why did i not think about that.. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. However, for the sake of learning you can also do this `"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -560)".match(/-?\d+/g).pop()` basically you have a regular expression matching for a possible `-` sign followed by multiple digits. We use the global `g` modifier so it doesn't stop at the first match and in this way our `match` function will return an array of matches and we can pop the last one (because that's the one we need).

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica FYI the values can be decimals

Comment: ah true, that complicates the regex a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing computed CSS is brittle; you might receive different values in different browsers which would have to be catered for.

From the comments on your question, you state that the CSS is...

> set in a js function

In that case, it would make sense to also record the relevant data in a more usable way. For example, using another data attribute

```js
const translateY = -560;
el.style.transform = `translateY(${translateY}px)`;
el.dataset.transformTranslateY = translateY;
```

Then you can easily read this value back at a later time

```js
const translateY = el.dataset.transformTranslateY;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this as an alternative approach, which gives direct access to the slot in the matrix we want.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('[data-holder]')
const transformValue = el.style.transform;

// A matrix can be represnted like this:
// matrix(a, b, c, d, e, f)

// Prints the final number in the matrix
console.log(
 new DOMMatrix(transformValue).f
)
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ro14x6tp/)